# Search gmail api by custom header

Tags: email, search, gmail-api, email-headers

I am trying to search gmail api with custom header (this case it is named  *notification-id*), but it does not work. Request I am making:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/tme/messages?includeSpamTrash=true&q=notification-id%3A560d01cef318893c3c000016
```

I tried the same query using default header (*rfc822msgid*) from google mail api and it works with this request:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?includeSpamTrash=true&q=rfc822msgid%3A560d01d068c_6690c6f31857290%40ip-172-31-12-127.mail`

Any ideas why it does not work with custom header?

Comment: There's a solution using a custom apps script, not a header, here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73544/179201

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to do this myself a while back, and came to the conclusion that it was not possible. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

According to the [Advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)-documentation, you can search for the following headers:

- **from, to, subject**
- **list:**

> Messages with the words info@example.com in the headers, sent to or
>   from this list

- **deliveredto:**

> Any message with username@gmail.com in the Delivered-To: field of the
>   message header (which can help you find messages forwarded from
>   another account or ones sent to an alias).

- **rfc822msgid:**

> Locates the exact message with the specified SMTP message-id.